# Как закрыть меню при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: javascript

Не получается сделать функцию закрытие меню по нажатии на ссылку. Для открытия и закрытия по кнопке использую следующий код:

```js
$(".mobileMenuHeading").on("click", function() {
  $(this).next(".sectionMenu").slideToggle("fast", function() {
    $(this).prev().html($(this).is(":visible") ? "Скрыть" : "Меню");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobileMenuHeading">Меню</div>
<ul class="sectionMenu">
  <li><a href="#cost"><span>Цены</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".mobileMenuHeading").on("click", function() {
  $(this).next(".sectionMenu").slideToggle("fast", function() {
    $(this).prev().html($(this).is(":visible") ? "Скрыть" : "Меню");
  });
});
$(".sectionMenu a").click(function(e) {
  $(".mobileMenuHeading").click();
});
$(".mobileMenuHeading").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobileMenuHeading">Меню</div>
<ul class="sectionMenu">
  <li><a href="#cost"><span>Цены</span></a></li>
</ul>
```